# Camera doesn't immediately finish changing positions after lerp

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on a camera controller that switches between a first-person mode and a third-person mode. I'm trying to smooth out the transition with `Vector3.Lerp()`, but the transition doesn't finish until a while after the camera is in the correct position. Here is my script:

```
using UnityEngine;

namespace Player
{
    public class CameraController : MonoBehaviour
    {
        // Other
        public CameraMode currentCameraMode = CameraMode.firstPerson;
        public float changeTime = 5;
        private bool isChanging = false;

        // References
        [Header("References")]
        public Camera playerCam;
        public Transform orientation;
        public Transform player;
        public Transform playerEyes;
        public Transform playerHead;

        // Looking
        [Header("Looking")]
        public float lookSensitivity = 5;
        private float xRotation = 0;

        public float minViewAngle = -85;
        public float maxViewAngle = 85;
        public bool invertedPitch = false;
        private Quaternion desiredRotation = Quaternion.identity;

        // Zooming
        [Header("Zooming")]
        public float offset = -5;
        public float zoomSensitivity = 10;
        public float minZoom = 2;
        public float maxZoom = 10;

        // Collision
        [Header("Collision")]
        public LayerMask collisionLayer;
        public bool drawDebugCollisionLines = false;
        private Vector3[] adjustedCameraClipPoints = new Vector3[5];
        private Vector3[] desiredCameraClipPoints = new Vector3[5];
        private Vector3 destination = Vector3.zero;
        private bool isColliding = false;

        private void Awake()
        {
            if (playerCam == null)
            {
                Debug.Log("No camera set! Defaulting to main camera.");
                playerCam = Camera.main;
            }
        }

        private void Start()
        {
            Initialize();
        }

        private void Update()
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F) || isChanging)
            {
                if ((currentCameraMode == CameraMode.firstPerson && !isChanging) || (currentCameraMode == CameraMode.thirdPerson && isChanging))
                {
                    Debug.Log("started changing");
                    currentCameraMode = CameraMode.thirdPerson;
                    desiredRotation = transform.rotation;
                    destination = player.position - (desiredRotation * Vector3.forward * offset);
                    transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, destination, Time.deltaTime * changeTime);
                    if (transform.position != destination || isColliding) isChanging = true;
                    else
                    {
                        isChanging = false;
                        Debug.Log("done changing");
                    }
                }
                else if ((currentCameraMode == CameraMode.thirdPerson && !isChanging) || (currentCameraMode == CameraMode.firstPerson && isChanging))
                {
                    Debug.Log("started changing");
                    currentCameraMode = CameraMode.firstPerson;
                    transform.rotation = desiredRotation;
                    transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, playerHead.position, Time.deltaTime * changeTime);
                    if (transform.position != playerHead.position) isChanging = true;
                    else
                    {
                        isChanging = false;
                        Debug.Log("done changing");
                    }
                }
            }

            if (currentCameraMode == CameraMode.firstPerson && !isChanging)
            {
                transform.position = playerHead.position;
            }
        }

        private void LateUpdate()
        {
            Look();
            Zoom();
        }

        private bool isCursorLocked = false;
        public void ToggleCursorLock()
        {
            if (isCursorLocked)
            {
                Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
                Cursor.visible = true;
                isCursorLocked = false;
                return;
            }

            Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
            Cursor.visible = false;
            isCursorLocked = true;
        }

        private void Look()
        {
            float yaw = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * lookSensitivity;
            float pitch = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * lookSensitivity;

            if (currentCameraMode == CameraMode.firstPerson)
            {
                Vector3 rotation = transform.localRotation.eulerAngles;
                yaw += rotation.y;

                xRotation -= pitch;
                xRotation = Mathf.Clamp(xRotation, -90, 90);

                player.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, yaw, 0);
                transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, yaw, 0);

                return;
            }

            orientation.position = player.position;
            orientation.rotation = desiredRotation;

            if (!invertedPitch) pitch = -pitch;

            float pitchMin = (90 - maxViewAngle) - Vector3.Angle(desiredRotation * Vector3.forward, Vector3.up);
            float pitchMax = Vector3.Angle(desiredRotation * Vector3.forward, Vector3.down) - (90 + minViewAngle);

            pitch = Mathf.Clamp(pitch, pitchMin, pitchMax);

            desiredRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, yaw, 0) * desiredRotation * Quaternion.Euler(pitch, 0, 0);

            HandleCollisions();

            transform.LookAt(player);
        }

        private void Zoom()
        {
            float scroll = Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") * zoomSensitivity;

            float zoom = Mathf.Clamp(offset - scroll, minZoom, maxZoom);

            offset = zoom;
        }

        private void DetectCollisions(Vector3 position, ref Vector3[] clipPoints)
        {
            clipPoints = new Vector3[5];

            float z = playerCam.nearClipPlane;
            float x = Mathf.Tan(playerCam.fieldOfView * 3.14f) * z;
            float y = x / playerCam.aspect;

            // Top-left
            clipPoints[0] = (transform.rotation * new Vector3(-x, y, z)) + position;
            // Top-right
            clipPoints[1] = (transform.rotation * new Vector3(x, y, z)) + position;
            // Bottom-left
            clipPoints[2] = (transform.rotation * new Vector3(-x, -y, z)) + position;
            // Bottom-right
            clipPoints[3] = (transform.rotation * new Vector3(x, -y, z)) + position;
            // Camera position
            clipPoints[4] = position - playerCam.transform.forward;

            for (int i = 0; i < clipPoints.Length; i++)
            {
                Ray ray = new Ray(player.position, clipPoints[i] - player.position);
                float distance = Vector3.Distance(clipPoints[i], player.position);
                if (Physics.Raycast(ray, distance, collisionLayer)) isColliding = true;
                else isColliding = false;
            }
        }

        private void HandleCollisions()
        {
            destination = player.position - (desiredRotation * Vector3.forward * offset);

            DetectCollisions(transform.position, ref adjustedCameraClipPoints);
            DetectCollisions(destination, ref desiredCameraClipPoints);

            if (isChanging && !isColliding) return;

            if (drawDebugCollisionLines)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                {
                    Debug.DrawLine(player.position, adjustedCameraClipPoints[i], Color.green);
                    Debug.DrawLine(player.position, desiredCameraClipPoints[i], Color.white);
                }
            }

            if (isColliding)
            {
                float distance = -1;

                for (int i = 0; i < desiredCameraClipPoints.Length; i++)
                {
                    Ray ray = new Ray(player.position, desiredCameraClipPoints[i] - player.position);
                    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out RaycastHit hit))
                    {
                        if (distance == -1) distance = hit.distance;
                        else if (hit.distance < distance) distance = hit.distance;
                    }
                }

                if (distance == -1) distance = 0;

                if (distance != 0)
                {
                    Vector3 desiredPosition = player.position - (desiredRotation * Vector3.forward * distance);
                    transform.position = desiredPosition;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                transform.position = destination;
            }
        }

        private void InitializeCameraMode()
        {
            if (currentCameraMode == CameraMode.firstPerson)
            {
                playerEyes.gameObject.SetActive(false);

                transform.position = playerHead.position;
            }
            if (currentCameraMode == CameraMode.thirdPerson)
            {
                playerEyes.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            }
        }

        private void Initialize()
        {
            orientation.parent = null;
            orientation.position = player.position;
            orientation.rotation = desiredRotation;

            desiredRotation = transform.rotation;

            offset = -offset;

            InitializeCameraMode();
            ToggleCursorLock();
        }
    }

    [System.Serializable]
    public enum CameraMode
    {
        firstPerson,
        thirdPerson
    }
}
```

If I turn up the change speed, the amount of time that you have to wait is lowered but the movement feels too fast. I hope someone answers this lol. ty

Comment: Too much code just for camera mode switching. e.g. we don't need to see collision code.  Only need to see [mcve]

Comment: `Time.deltaTime * changeTime` - appears to be `{a very small number} * {a constant}` which isn't going to yield the 0 -> 1 that a clean Lerp requires. Secondly, `transform.position != destination` - will be very unreliable, because you're working with floats and your current code will not land on an _exact_ match.

Comment: When the change starts, store the current position and set a counter to 0. Each frame, add `Time.deltaTime/changeTime` to that counter. Use its value directly in lerp between the stored position and the destination. Do this using localPosition on a gameobject separate to the one(s) directly controlled by the player such that they aren't able to "fight" the animation. When the counter is >=1, the transition is completed.

Comment: Also a side note: keep in mind that the camera will pass through the characters head for such a transition, so you'll want to have the character mesh fade or something to avoid some nasty UX such as the rear of the characters head briefly filling the screen creating a flash jank, and/ or geometry being briefly visible (such as the rear of eyes whilst the camera is inside the head)